# Error fastboot flash system

Tags: fastboot, operating-system

Hey i have phone xiaomi mi a2 try install another OS but get this error any ideas? need faster, cuz i can't run phone stuck on android one logo

> PS C:\add> fastboot flash system C:\add\pixel.img
>   target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
>   sending sparse 'system' (524284 KB)...
>   OKAY [ 16.264s]
>   writing 'system'...
>   OKAY [  0.002s]
>   sending sparse 'system' (488200 KB)...
>   FAILED (command write failed (Unknown error))

Answer (score 0):

First you need to unlock your bootloader and then you can flash recovery image.
If you have already done that, Check whether you are flashing the proper one.

This is [TWRP recovery](http://downloadmirror.co/2CSv/TWRP-3.2.3-jasmine-20180804.img) for MI A2.

After flashing TWRP you can flash the desired rom from it. Do read some threads from XDA, If you are not sure about what you are doing.